# Data Modeling: Is it always necessary to use an intersection table?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

Consider the following:

I have two tables (Customers and Cases) defined as follows:

```
**Customers**
CustomerId (PK)
CustomerName
CustomerPhone

**Cases**
CaseId (PK)
CaseManager
CaseNotes
```

Each customer can have an unlimited amount of cases, however each case can only belong to one customer. So in order to relate the tables to each other, I would use an intersection table (CustomerCases), that consists of the foreign keys from each table respectively.

However, couldn't I just add the CustomerID from the Customers table as a foreign key to the Cases table?  I feel like I'm missing something. Are there any pitfalls that I should be aware of should I choose not to use an intersection table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If one case can belong only to one customer, it seems totally reasonable to me that you just add a CustomerID FK to the Cases table.
If you think that requirement might eventually change (e.g. a case might have multiple customers), then the intersection table approach might make more sense.
Also unless you have an indefinite number of CaseManagers, it might also make sense to have a Managers table and have a FK from the Cases table to that.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm new here, and I can't tell you how much it means get a thorough answer so quickly!

Answer (score 7):

An "intersection" (aka "junction" or "cross-reference") table is only necessary to model a many-to-many relationship.  In this situation, a Case participates in a many-to-one relationship with a Customer.  So, a foreign key is all that is required -- and indeed that would be a more conventional solution.  Avoid the unnecessary complexity of a junction table -- unless there is an architectural reason to the contrary (e.g. the application relies upon a component that demands that all relationships be represented using junctions).

Comment: Much appreciated!  You've saved me a lot of headache!  Thanks again!

Comment: +1 for terminology and explaining what type relationship necessitates this model